# Alert notification when Cluster failover happens

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, failovercluster

Is there any way to get notification emails when cluster failover happens along with which is active node information?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a T-SQL SQL Job to check the role of the db on local server. If it changes, use SQL Server database mail to send an email. Or raise a specific error and define an alert for that error.
-- check the role of a db in an availability group:

```
SELECT  ars.role
FROM master.sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states ars
JOIN master.sys.databases dbs
ON ars.replica_id = dbs.replica_id
WHERE dbs.name = DB_NAME()
```

role: 
0 = Resolving
1 = Primary
2 = Secondary

Comment: Am looking something like this : alert email stating "failover has happened, now the active node is ****".

Comment: script which you have provided is for alwayson group. Our servers are not configured with always on.

Comment: my bad. For fail over cluster, you might need to use PS